# Python pyinstaller windows exe with openssl

Tags: python, windows, compilation, openssl, executable

I have for the last few days testing the ability to create a windows executable from a python script that requires pyOpenSSL.  I am getting an error that I am not sure how to solve or even a point of reference to solve.  I have some applications that I want to use pyOpenSSL, then compile into an windows exe.  I am doing this right now with a Chilkat library (www.chilkatsoft.com/) but now want to use other modules that need pyOpenSSL.

The error that I get when I execute my single or directory compiled application is

```
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'H:\\Dev\\BS_DEV\\Win_Env\\ENV_Tests\\test_gen_cert\\build\\out00-PYZ.pyz\\__pycache__\\_Cryptography_cffi_f3e4673fx399b1113.c'
```

The test code that I am using will generate a public and private certificate, this runs ok when executed using the .py file.

```
from OpenSSL import crypto, SSL
from socket import gethostname
from pprint import pprint
from time import gmtime, mktime
from os.path import exists, join

CERT_FILE = "myapp.crt"
KEY_FILE = "myapp.key"

def create_self_signed_cert():
    """
    If datacard.crt and datacard.key don't exist in cert_dir, create a new
    self-signed cert and keypair and write them into that directory.
    """
    cert_dir = '.'
    if not exists(join(cert_dir, CERT_FILE)) \
            or not exists(join(cert_dir, KEY_FILE)):

        # create a key pair
        k = crypto.PKey()
        k.generate_key(crypto.TYPE_RSA, 1024)

        # create a self-signed cert
        cert = crypto.X509()
        cert.get_subject().C = "US"
        cert.get_subject().ST = "Minnesota"
        cert.get_subject().L = "Minnetonka"
        cert.get_subject().O = "my company"
        cert.get_subject().OU = "my organization"
        cert.get_subject().CN = gethostname()
        cert.set_serial_number(1000)
        cert.gmtime_adj_notBefore(0)
        cert.gmtime_adj_notAfter(10*365*24*60*60)
        cert.set_issuer(cert.get_subject())
        cert.set_pubkey(k)
        cert.sign(k, 'sha1')

        open(join(cert_dir, CERT_FILE), "wt").write(
            crypto.dump_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert))
        open(join(cert_dir, KEY_FILE), "wt").write(
            crypto.dump_privatekey(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, k))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    create_self_signed_cert()
```

I have been using pyinstaller before and have compiled openssl programs with it on my OSX (Mac) box.

Here is my spec file:

```
# -*- mode: python -*-
block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['scert.py'],
             pathex=['H:\\Dev\\BS_DEV\\Win_Env\\ENV_Tests\\test_gen_cert'],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=None,
             runtime_hooks=None,
             excludes=None,
             cipher=block_cipher)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          a.binaries + [
                  ('ssleay32.dll', 'C:\\openssl-1.0.1i\\bin\\ssleay32.dll', 'BINARY'),
                  ('libeay32.dll', 'C:\\openssl-1.0.1i\\bin\\libeay32.dll', 'BINARY'),
                ],
          a.zipfiles,
          a.datas,
          name='scert.exe',
          debug=False,
          strip=None,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
```

I have compiled my own version of OpenSSL and used pre compiled windows binaries.

Here is some information on my environment:
Windows 8 64 bit with 8 GiG of RAM
Python 2.7.6 (default, Nov 10 2013, 19:24:24) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Any Ideas??

Has anyone ever package a windows executable from a python script that requires OpenSSL?

If this cannot be done, is there another package tool (opensource or purchase) that I can solve this problem?

Thank you
Tom

OK, I think I might have found an answer, I got it working but need to verify this on another computer.
I noticed that the error was coming from cffi wanting to compile something (not sure what it was) at the time of execution and/or not finding what cffi compiled.  So I looked around and was going to recompile cryptography and cffi.  Since I was on windows I then installed the free pyOpenSSL package from (www.egenix.com/products/python/pyOpenSSL/).  From that I was able to compile my script into an executable.

I just compiled it into a directory and was able to see all the files, here is a list of what was in my dist directory:

```
OpenSSL.SSL.pyd
OpenSSL.crypto.pyd
OpenSSL.rand.pyd
_ctypes.pyd
_hashlib.pyd
_socket.pyd
_ssl.pyd
bz2.pyd
libeay32.dll
microsoft.vc90.crt.manifest
msvcm90.dll
msvcp90.dll
msvcr90.dll
msvcrt.dll
mx.DateTime.mxDateTime.mxDateTime.pyd
mx.TextTools.mxTextTools.mxTextTools.pyd
mx.Tools.mxTools.mxTools.pyd
python27.dll
pywintypes27.dll
scert.exe
scert.exe.manifest
select.pyd
ssleay32.dll
unicodedata.pyd
user32.dll
win32api.pyd
win32evtlog.pyd
```

I will be doing more testing tonight
TJ

Comment: Ive been struggling with this for years ... (without really investing too much effort in finding a solution...) heres to hoping for a good answer